# Cannot connect Collection View to View Controller Code. 'Error unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I am trying to add a collection view to my custom view controller called "cardsViewController". When I run the build, I get the error [UIViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have connected the collection view's data source and delegate to the view controller in the storyboard and added "UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate" after the class name in the code. I have also connected the view controller in the storyboard to the code by adding "CardsViewController" (same name as the code file) to the custom class field of the view controller.

```
import UIKit

class CardsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

}
```

I want xcode to recognize that the view controller code file is responsible for controlling the collection view.

[identity inspector of Cards View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2lJR.png)

[connections inspector of the collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCYMC.png)

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when you set the wrong view controller in interface builder. Make sure that `Custom Class` in `Identity Inspector` matches exactly your view controller class name (`CardsViewController`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Make sure that Custom Class in Identity Inspector of what should match the view controller class name?

Comment: It's because "Inherit Module from target" needs to be checked. My class name was correct.